# Error in my code: The constructor Scanner() is undefined. Syntax error, insert "( )" to complete Expression

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm running Eclipse.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner; // Creates scanner object

        System.out.println("Enter a line of text: "); // Outputs the prompt

        String Line = input.nextLine(); //wait for user to enter line of text 

        System.out.println("You entered: " + Line); //Tells user what they entered
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>       The constructor Scanner() is undefined
>       Syntax error, insert "( )" to complete Expression
>
> at Input.main(Input.java:7)

Comment: Although you already have an answer, if you were wondering why some had voted your question negative, its because of a very apparent error with clear description. If you are new to coding, you should instead start by trying to fix this : `System.out.println"Hello World";`

Comment: System.out.println("Hello World");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, First of all, a constructor call needs parentheses, even if there are no parameters (It is still a function call)

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(); <<<
```

And put "System.in" inside these! System.in is an input stream, meaning a way to get input, and thats what the Scanner needs to work!

```
    new Scanner(System.in);
```

It should work now, bye!

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a constructor without `()`, and you need a thing to read from. Change

```
Scanner input = new Scanner;
```

to

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: OK, I have it now. Thank you!